# Why does the cursor blink in the center of the comment box?

Tags: bug, comments, microsoft-edge

Look at this beautiful comment box:

[image: StackOverflow Comment Box]

On Windows 10 with Microsoft Edge, **conversely to ArchLinux + KDE with Mozilla Firefox**, the cursor blinks at the **second** line, not on the first.

Point is, it somehow seems unintuitive to me.

Is this intentional? Could you make the cursor blink at the **first** line instead, please? Or do you actually *like* it?

Comment: Works just fine on my Win10 machine.  You need to name your browser.

Comment: @HansPassant Done. Seems to be Microsoft Edge-specific then.

Comment: Confirmed it's an Edge thing. .Works fine in Chrome, IE, FF.