# Keyboard problem when editing

Tags: discussion, bug

I'm facing strange problem while editing questions/answers.

My <kbd>Up</kbd> key works only up to the beginning of the paragraph where cursor is present (in other words it works up to first linebreak above the cursor). No matter if it's code or normal text. To go to upper paragraph, I've to use mouse, and then I can use the key normally, up to next linebreak.

As I've tried on website it works normal, only when editing.

It's probably browser dependent, but maybe somebody can check it and confirm.

I've tested on two computers, though with the same browser - MS Edge.

Comment: Edge has known [quirky cursor problems](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310810/why-does-the-cursor-blink-in-the-center-of-the-comment-box).  Try another one.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes - Edge specific problem - on IE works just fine.